# How to develop for iPhone OS 2.2.1 with the latest iPhone SDK 3.2.2?

Tags: iphone, xcode

Is this possible to develop for iPhone OS 2.2.1 with the latest iPhone SDK 3.2.2? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iPhone SDK 3.2.2 is under NDA.  You should ask this question on http://devforums.apple.com.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is anymore unless you can find the actual 2.2.1 sdk to download somewhere. If you can, then yes. But, as far as Apple is concerned, they really only want 3.0+ apps on the App Store.

Comment: Actually, seems like you have an old install on your computer. Have you tried changing the "Base SDK" in your XCode project to 2.2.1? That should do it. I always change my Base SDK from 3.1.1 to 3.0 for my Apps.